# Writing Chinese characters in a PDF Response in c#

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm having problems with generating a PDF with Chinese chars in it.
I download the html as a string from "pageurl" and I use NRECO.Pdfgenerator to generate bytes for pdf from it.

On the pdf, I can see latin characters correctly but not chinese ones. I assume it's an encoding problem but i cannot seem to understand where the mistake is.
Heres the code i'm using:

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string htmlstring = client.DownloadString(PageUrl);

    //Nreco
    HtmlToPdfConverter converter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();

    converter.CustomWkHtmlArgs = "--encoding UTF-8";
    converter.GeneratePdf(htmlstring);

    byte[] result = converter.GeneratePdf(htmlstring);

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.BinaryWrite(result);
    Response.Flush();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use itextPdf! Look at this posts: [How to display chinese characters in pdf file created with iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999403/how-to-display-chinese-characters-in-pdf-file-created-with-itextsharp)

http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=201

Answer (score 1):

You can use pdfclown which is free and can write almost all languages in pdf

You can download it [here](http://pdfclown.org/)

You can use any type of font which supports unicode characters