# retrieving the chinese and japanese text from db using resultset and have to write in PDF using iText library

Tags: java, oracle, encoding, character-encoding, itext

I have retrieve the chinese and japanese text from db using resultset and have to write in PDF, so i was trying to do this using oracle db and itext pdf but when i get the chinese text from db, it shows question marks and not able to write it to pdf

Comment: How about using `HELVETICA` (standard 14 fonts) and `CP1252` encoding ?

Comment: Try out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999403/how-to-display-chinese-characters-in-pdf-file-created-with-itextsharp) . It may help you.

Comment: Thanks Ashish, I tried 2nd option of using FontSelector but still the chinese words are not added in PDF. I am getting chinese text from DB in a string and then i am trying write it in PDF. and I can see the chinese text in DB as it is but after retrieval in java string something is happening.. Please help..

Comment: Are you still getting the same error? I mean the question marks?

Comment: In pdf i am not getting any chinese words, just the blank pdf is generated

Comment: If you have any small example, could you please post it, may be that will help.. in my case chinese text is in db and and generating pdf in java

Comment: Here you can find the examples about [Adding Chinese text with iText](http://developers.itextpdf.com/frequently-asked-developer-questions?id=395)

Comment: Also you should see `Joel Engineer`'s answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0aba545a-c8ba-4389-9439-fcad416ee60d/display-chinesejapanese-characters-in-pdf-in-itextsharp-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral) and refer [this](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/196019/display-chinese-characters-in-pdf-created-by-itext) and [this](https://www.codeproject.com/questions/341142/itextsharp-read-pdf-file).

Comment: Missing text is usually due to the font not being embedded, have a look at http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/font-examples/examples-font-tutorial#15-f03_embedded.java for how to embed a font in itext5.