# Unable to insert French characters from DB(VARCHAR2 column) into PdfPCell using itext

Tags: java, itext

I am reading French Characters from oracle database(VARCHAR2 column) and trying to print them to a PDF. But the special characters like ą are being ignored in the PDF. Please suggest how can I print the same character into the PDF.
I am using itext to create the PDF.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried setting character set yo UTF-8 before writing to document.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999403/how-to-display-chinese-characters-in-pdf-file-created-with-itextsharp. This is for Chinese characters, can you try same thing for your case?

Comment: @verisimilitude no it did not work.

Comment: @Lakshman yes I tried that but still the special chars are being ignored.