# Itext sharp/Itext 5 display Chinese characters

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation, itext7, cjk

I am using itextsharp version 5.5.13.2

I am trying the solution in [How to display chinese characters in pdf file created with iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999403/how-to-display-chinese-characters-in-pdf-file-created-with-itextsharp) but it did not work it is not displaying anything. my document is blank.

```
FontSelector selector = new FontSelector();
selector.AddFont(FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12));
selector.AddFont(FontFactory.GetFont("MSung-Light", "UniCNS-UCS2-H", BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED));
Phrase ph = selector.Process("全澳甲流确诊病例已破");
document.Add(new Paragraph(ph));
```

I am trying to find a solution

I also tried the solution below but it errors b/se the AddToResourceSearch method is not available.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0aba545a-c8ba-4389-9439-fcad416ee60d/display-chinesejapanese-characters-in-pdf-in-itextsharp-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral

```
public iTextSharp.text.Font CreateChineseFont()
        {
            BaseFont.AddToResourceSearch("iTextAsian.dll");
            BaseFont.AddToResourceSearch("iTextAsianCmaps.dll"); //"STSong-Light", "UniGB-UCS2-H", 
            BaseFont baseFT=BaseFont.CreateFont("STSong-Light", "UniGB-UCS2-H", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(baseFT);
            return font;
        }


Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4,50, 50, 50, 50);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("Chap11.pdf", FileMode.Create));
document.Open();
iTextSharp.text.Font font = CreateChineseFont();
document.Add(new Paragraph("全澳甲流确诊病例已破", font));
document.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I needed to import the following packages via Nugget

**System.Text.Encoding and
System.Text.Encoding.CodePages**

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text;
using System.Text;

public static class ItextSharpRenderer
    {
        public static Phrase CreatePhrase(string text)
        {

            FontSelector selector = new FontSelector();
            selector.AddFont(FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12));
            selector.AddFont(FontFactory.GetFont("Arial Unicode MS", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED));
            return selector.Process(text);
        }


        private static void InitializeFonts()
        {
            Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
            FontFactory.Register("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\ARIALUNI.TTF");

        }

        public static void RenderCJK()
        {

                InitializeFonts();
                Document pdfDoc = new Document();
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream("C:\\HelenProjects\\Helen_IronPDFSample\\A_TestPDF.pdf", FileMode.Create));
                pdfDoc.Open();

                pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph(CreatePhrase("hello part1 全澳甲流确诊病例已破")));

                pdfDoc.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("The file was created.");
                Console.ReadLine();

    }
    }
```

You can copy and put ARIALUNI.TTF in in any folder and use it from there or put it in the project files and refer from there.